# Copy Google Doc template and use as body for email

Tags: google-apps-script

I have quite a long email template I want to automatically send to welcome new users.
The script copies the body of a Google Doc and uses that as the body of the email using MailApp.sendEmail.

The issue is that the email that arrives is very narrow and doesn't copy exactly what is in the template. Is there any way of formatting this to make it the same as the Google Doc template?

Any help much appreciated

var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/"doc id"/edit");

```
      var body = doc.getBody().getText();
      var message = body;
      var subject = "subject line";
      MailApp.sendEmail (user.primaryEmail, subject, message)
```

Comment: Try reading about templated html in documentation

Comment: You can either create an html message body or convert your doc into a pdf and add it as attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned something new with this:

1. When you send an email as a plain text email it won't let you control where the line breaks are
2. It actually adds line breaks when you call the `.getText()` method, as well as part of the `.sendEmail` method when you are sending it just as plain text.

The easiest solution is to send it as an HTML message.  I experimented with this and have what I believe the easiest solution for it below:

```
//this will replace the line breaks with html line breaks
var htmlBody = doc.getBody().getText().replace(/\n/g,'<br/>'); 

var message = 
     { 
        to: user.primaryEmail,
        subject: 'subject line',
        htmlBody: htmlBody
     }

MailApp.sendEmail ({message})
```

I've tested this and this should fix your problem.